# grep and print how many times my pattern in file 1 is present in file2

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a file1 (list of my pattern) like this:

file1

```
Fatty_acid_degradation
Aminobenzoate_degradation
Amino_sugar_and_nucleotide_sugar_metabolism
Amoebiasis
```

and I have a file2 (list of all the patterns).

file2

```
Fatty_acid_degradation
Fatty_acid_degradation
Fatty_acid_degradation
Bacterial_invasion_of_epithelial_cells
Bacterial_invasion_of_epithelial_cells
Bacterial_invasion_of_epithelial_cells
Bacterial_invasion_of_epithelial_cells
```

I would like to grep and count how many times each of my patterns in file1 is present in file2 and obtain a table (tab separated) like this:

```
Fatty_acid_degradation 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to `grep` each of the patterns and then count them:

```
$ grep -Fwf file1 file2 | sort | uniq -c
      3 Fatty_acid_degradation
```

The `grep` options are `-f` to give a file as a list of patterns to search for, `-F` to specify that the pattern should be treated as a string and not a regular expression and `-w` to ensure that the pattern is matched only against entire words (so that `regulation_of_expression` is not matched against `upregulation_of_excpression` for example).

Then, you can use whatever tool you prefer to change the format:

```
$ grep -Fwf file1 file2 | sort | uniq -c | sed -r 's/.*([0-9]+) *(.*)/\2\t\1/'
$ grep -Fwf file1 file2 | sort | uniq -c | perl -lane 'print "$F[1]\t$F[0]"'
$ grep -Fwf file1 file2 | sort | uniq -c | awk -vOFS="\t" '{print $2,$1}'
```

All of the above return

```
Fatty_acid_degradation  3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -f file1 file2 | sort | uniq -c
```

This gives the output in the format:

```
  3 Fatty_acid_degradation
```

Can you live with that?

Answer (score 0):

so many quick answer, make me feel awkward ...

```
awk 'FNR == NR { pat[$1]=0 ; next ; }
{ if ( $0 in pat ) pat[$0]++ ; }
END { for ( p in pat ) if ( pat[p]) printf "%s %d\n",p,pat[p] ;}' f1 f2
```

where

- `FNR == NR { pat[$1]=0 ; next ; }` record pattern in pat array
- `{ if ( $0 in pat ) pat[$0]++ ; }` whenever one is matched, count
- `END { for ( p in pat ) if ( pat[p]) printf "%s %d\n",p,pat[p] ;}` at the end, dump non zero count

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following solution using Python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import collections
with open('file_1') as f1, open('file_2') as f2:
    counts = collections.Counter(f2)
    for line in f1:
        if line in counts:
            print line.rstrip() + '\t' + str(counts[line])
```

Here we have used the `Counter` class of `collections` module which will generate a dictionary containing the occurrences of each element of an iterable.